# Postpone fragment transaction from a fragment to play a custom animation

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-transitions

I have such a case:

My fragment should be aware of a next transaction event and, at the end, start a custom animation, which will be played inside a composable, and then, continue the transaction.
The problem is that I cannot control the transaction process, my fragment is being used from another module, which rules the fragment flow.

Are there any possible solutions?

I've tried using methods like `getExitTransition()` and `exitTransition =` (in `onCreate()`) using `Hold()` and even `Fade()` transition, but it doesn't work.